# Can't make files/dir writable by php

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions, silverstripe

I'm having issues making files and directories writeable by PHP on a CentOS 7 machine

I've already search the net and the site but haven't found a solution that works for me (I'm fairly new to linux).

So far I've tried the following, any ideas on why the file/dirs are still not writeable by PHP?

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache ss/
sudo chmod -R g+rw ss/

sudo chmod -R 777 ss/
```

Also tried the following command after finding the id with echo getmyuid().':'.getmygid();

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 ss/
```

I've run the following commands

```
# egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
User apache
Group apache

ls -Zd ss/
drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ss/
```

Comment: What is the PHP code you are using? Are you sure you are accessing to the correct dir/file? Also, what is the output of "ls -la" for the dir "ss"?

Comment: show what you;ve tried

Comment: You really did not get any errors back when using the commands above? What account is the http server executed as? Is that account and group _really_ called "apache"? That is _not_ very common... Then: where is that folder `ss` located you are trying to use? It is probably less confusing to use absolute addressing. In general: a file permission of `0777` is usually _not_ required and a very bad habit. You should not use that. It introduces a huge security hole into your system.

Comment: what is the security context of this folder? check it with 
`ls -Zd ss/`

Comment: I used the account and group apache from the following command on another answer

# egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
User apache
Group apache

The ss folder location is /var/www/html/ss

The security context command returned
drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ss/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a selinux restriction, try changing the context to httpd_sys_rw_content_t using: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t ss/`

Regards,